# Constrained KnapSack Problem

Tags: algorithms

I was practising some Codechef problems and I am stuck on this problem :

Malvika has created n programming contests. Each of the contests has three problems, categorized as easy, medium and hard on difficulty level. For the ith contest, easy problem takes TE[i] hours and gives you PE[i] pleasure. Similarly, medium problem takes TM[i] hours, gives PM[i] pleasure, and a hard one has the values TH[i], PH[i].

Today, Animesh wanted to practice some of them. Animesh has a really bad habit of trying problems for only a few minutes and saying to Malvika "I am a noob, you are a pro. It's some weird stuff I don't know. Please, tell me the solution, bro!" Having been irritated by this behaviour numerous times in the past, she granted him K special powers he can use before starting the practice session. By using a single power, Animesh can pick any two problems irrespective of their difficulty from two different contests and swap them.

Animesh has at max time hours before he gets frustrated by his noobness and ends the practice session. He wants to make the maximum use of it by getting as much pleasure out of this activity as possible. Animesh also gets bored with the contest themes fairly quickly, so he does not want to solve more than one problem from any contest. Can you help Animesh in estimating the maximum amount of pleasure he can achieve out of this activity?

I can identify its a constrained Knapsack problem but cannot think of a suitable algorithm to implement it.

---

Can anyone please help me?

(I thought that its suitable as a Math problem because I want only the algorithm. Your answer need not be code oriented.)

Comment: I don't quite understand the usefulness of the special powers. What exactly does Animesh gain by swapping two problems from two different contests?

Comment: If I understand correctly, he only wants to solve at most one problem from each contest, but by swapping he can circumvent this.

Comment: @relep I think exactly what you said

Comment: @SplitInfinity Swapping means Easy Problem of contest 1 can be interchanged with Medium Problem of contest 2 and thus the time and pleasures associated with them also gets interchanged (I think time and pleasures also get interchanged, though not explicitly mentioned)

Comment: If the times and pleasures would not be interchanged then swapping would have no practical effect at all.

Comment: @relep Absolutely. They implicitly impled that t&ps  get interchanged.

Comment: @relep Not true. The special power can still be useful if times and pleasures are not interchanged:

Suppose there is a contest $H$ with three very hard problems that take a long time and have low pleasure values, and a contest $E$ with three very easy problems that do not take a long time and have high pleasure values. Without the special power, he can only do one problem from $E$, and has a choice of doing one problem from $H$ or doing none. But with the special power, he can do two of the problems in $E$ (by moving one of them to $H$).

Comment: @blargen nice catch!